# Spinner doesn't work on click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-spinner

I have created a simple spinner in my site, but it's not working for mouseclick the beauty is using through keyboard the spinner is working don't know why its not working through mouseclick I don't know what causes this isssue?

I have attached the code below I didn't attached the entire code I just attached the spinner code only please see it below

```
me(".items_container .item_spinner").click(function() { 
    var count = me(".droppable .item_spinner").length;       
    var count = count + 1;
    var step = me(".step").val();   
    var li_div = '<li class="item_spinner" id="item_spinner_'+count+'">';
    li_div += '<label class="spin_' + count + '"><b>Spinner</b></label><input type="text" id="spinner-3_' + count + '" value="0" />';
    li_div += '<input type="button" class="edit" id="editspinner_' + count + '" value="Edit">';
    li_div += '<a href="javascript:(void);" class="removeclass" style=""></a>';
    li_div += '<div class="editspinnerrange_' + count + '" style="display:none;">';
    li_div += '<label>Field Label</label><input type="text" name="spinner_title"  class="spinner_label_' + count + '">';
    li_div += '<label>Min Range Value</label><input type="text" name="minrange" class="minchange_' + count + '">';
    li_div += '<span class="minranges_' + count + '" style="display:none;">-1000</span>';
    li_div += '<label>Max Range Value</label><input type="text" name="maxrange" class="maxchange_' + count + '">';
    li_div += '<span class="maxranges_' + count + '" style="display:none;">1000</span>';
    li_div += '<label>Step Increase</label><input type="text" name="step"  class="step_' + count + '"><span class="stepchange_' + count + '" style="display:none;">1</span></div><div class="spinneroptionbox_' + count + '" style="display:none;"><span class="req">Make this field as required <input class="spinneroption_' + count + '" type="checkbox" name="required" ></span></div></li>';
    me('.droppable').append(li_div); 
    me(document).on('keyup', '.spinner_label_' + count, function() {
        me('.spinner_label_'+count).val(me(this).val());
        me('.spin_' + count).html('<b>' + me(this).val() + '</b>'); 
    }); 
    me(document).on('keyup', '.maxchange_' + count, function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var newmax = me('.maxchange_' + count).val();
        me('.maxranges_' + count).text(newmax);
        var newmin = me('.minhange_' + count).val();
        me('.minranges_' + count).text(newmin);
        me('#spinner-3_' + count).spinner({ 
            step: me('.stepchange_' + count).text(), 
            min: me('.minranges_' + count).text(), 
            max: me('.maxranges_' + count).text(),
        });
    });  
    me(document).on('keyup', '.minchange_' + count, function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var newmin = me('.minchange_' + count).val();
        me('.minranges_' + count).text(newmin);
        me('#spinner-3_' + count).spinner({
            step: me('.stepchange_' + count).text(), 
            min: me('.minranges_' + count).text(), 
            max: me('.maxranges_' + count).text(),
        }); 
    });  
    me(document).on('keyup', '.step_' + count, function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var newstep = me('.step_' + count).val();
        me('.stepchange_' + count).text(newstep);
        me('#spinner-3_' + count).spinner({
            step: me('.stepchange_' + count).text(), 
            min: me('.minranges_' + count).text(), 
            max: me('.maxranges_' + count).text(),
        });
    }); 
    me('#spinner-3_' + count).spinner({
        step: me('.stepchange_' + count).text(), 
        min: me('.minranges_' + count).text(), 
        max: me('.maxranges_' + count).text(),
    }); 
    me('#editspinner_' + count).click(function() {
        $data = me(this).parent().attr('id');
        me('.spinneroption_' + count).attr('data-curr', $data);
        me('.editspinnerrange_' + count).slideToggle("milliseconds");
        me('.spinneroptionbox_' + count).slideToggle("milliseconds");
    }); 
    me('.spinneroption_' + count).live('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $curr = me(this).attr('data-curr');
            me('#' + $curr + ' label').eq(0).after('<span class="required">*</span>');
        } else {
            me(this).parents('li').children('.required').remove();          
        }
    });     
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="item_spinner" class="item_spinner ui-widget-content">
    <a href="#" class="spipop">
        <input type="button" value="Spinner">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the html dom structure as well. if possible create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You're using me(document).on('keyup', '.step_'+count,function () { for other events but using  me( '#editspinner_'+count).click(function() { for the click?

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed in jQuery 1.9. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: As @Regent pointed out you have used `live()` and `on()` together. its always good to maintain the latest method `on()`. ref :http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Regent,dreamweiver I have changed live to 'on' still not working

Comment: @Sri I didn't say it is solution for your issue :) It is just "bad" place in code.

Comment: @Regent Okay thanks any other solution to work on this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `click` event is not working  is because the html dom is dynamically generated which needs to handled as a delegated event.

This should fix your problem.

**jQuery code:**

```
      me(document).on('click','#editspinner_'+count,function() {
        $data = me(this).parent().attr('id');
        me('.spinneroption_'+count).attr('data-curr', $data);
        me( '.editspinnerrange_'+count).slideToggle( "milliseconds" );
        me( '.spinneroptionbox_'+count).slideToggle( "milliseconds" );
     });
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have tried this also not working any other solution

Comment: @Sri: hey bro there is a serious syntax error,`<div id="` **item_spinner** `" class="` **item_spinner** ` ui-widget-content"><a href="#" class="spipop" ><input type="button" value="Spinner"></a></div>`. you have used same name for `id` & `class` selectors, hence its conflicting when its clicked.

Comment: Also I doubt that `.slideToggle("milliseconds")` has correct duration.

Comment: @dreamweiver not working bro I changed the thing as you mentioned but no changes I cant put in jsfiddle because the code is in php format If I paste in it it won't work so only just paste the area where error is showing

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for u , could you added the definition of .spinner() function , also the way js code was written was confusing. so i have corrected as much as i know. http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/qfzeoezn/3/